# separar datos unidos por '-' en Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2008-r2

Registro original

```
AGU-120201007-25MO1401-INVERSION-ORDINARIO-C-SIST
```

Quiero que me quede el siguiente resultado

```
EMPRESA : AGU
AGRUPADOR : 120201007
CODIGO: 25MO1401
TIPO : INVERSION
ASIENTO : ORDINARIO
CENTROCOSTO : C-SIST
```

Comment: Hola, debes especificar que base de datos es la que utilizas y que es lo que has intentado

Comment: quiero que me separe los datos pero que no me quite letras ni me falten

Comment: El problema es que los registros que me manda la longuitud varia

Comment: unos tiene 43, o 49 o 53

Comment: Queres una columna por pedazo del dato? no importa que sean de distintas longitudes

Comment: Si mi estimado que me quede un resultado asi:
EMPRESA | AGRUPADOR | CODIGO |TIPO | ASIENTO | CENTROCOSTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias separarlo con la funcion string_split

```
select user from STRING_SPLIT('valor1-valor2','-')
```

Esta funcion termina mostrando los datos de esta manera

```
user
valor1
valor2
```

Pero mostrarlo de la manera que tu deseas solo en una columna si deseas tener una referencia completa a la documentacion de esta funcion la encuentras en microsft docs o si deseas la funcion en otras bases de datos tendrias que revisar especificamente su documentacion

Comment: LO TOMO ENCUENTO AMIGO SOLO QUE QUIERO QUE ME QUEDEN HORIZONTAL AÑADIENDOLES UN ALIAS

Comment: Lo siento pero no hay funcion que te lo haga conforme a lo que te investigado tendrias que darlos por separado